# How would I change the docker's base directory

Tags: docker, volume

All my docker related folders are saved in /var/lib/docker. But my / space is very limited. Hence, I would like all of the content present inside this location to go to say /home/User/my_space. How would I do that? I could use symbolic link. But, that will only move the current contents of the location. I would like to move the future changes of the docker also. Please help me :)

Answer (score 1):

Symlink is an universal solution which works, I've successfully used it plenty of times. I do not recommend using the path you suggested, though, since the files should be owned by either the `root` or `docker` users, depending on your distro/OS. Therefore, if you want to use the `/home` partition, then:

- shut down docker
- `mv /var/lib/docker /home/`
- `ln -s /home/docker /var/lib/docker`
- start docker

This will usually persist through upgrades unless you uninstall and reinstall Docker.

Now, more recent versions of Docker support an option in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`, namely the `data-root` option. So just edit the file and add

```
{
  "data-root": "/home/docker"
}
```

You can find the whole schema for the file in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-configuration-file).